# Size of memory allocated on heap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, heap-memory

Can you check the size memory allocated on heap if the buffer contains '0' characters?

```
char *c = new char[6]; //random size memory
memset(c, 0, 6);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reliable way to do that - you have to store that information yourself.

`operator new[]()` function can be implemented (and replaced by you) in whatever way so you just can't know the size unless you know the exact implementation in details.

In Visual C++ the default implementation for built-in types is to just forward calls to `malloc()` - then you could try `_msize()`, but again it's unportable and maybe even unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

No, in general<sup>1</sup> you can't. You have to store this information separately.

If you need to use that memory as a string or as an array, my advice is to use a `std::string` or `std::vector`, which do all this bookkeeping by themselves.

---

1. i.e. "as far as the standard is concerned"

---

I see that your question is MSVC++-specific; in that case, some heap-debugging helpers [are provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc28wkas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but they work only when the project is compiled in debug mode; I think there's some other compiler-specific function to get the allocated size, but it wouldn't work if custom allocators are used.

On the other hand, APIs like [`LocalAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) let you know how big is the allocated chunk of memory (see e.g. [`LocalSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

But again, I think that it's a cleaner design to keep track of this information by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to store the amount of allocated memory as a separate variable, and you need to take it with you whenever you want to do something with your allocated structure. This is cumbersome, but may be fast. As a safe and comfortable replacement use std::vector, boost::array, etc.